# SurfaceView drawing failure

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, ondraw, surfaceholder

I am trying an example having `SurfaceView`. I have inherited my class from `SurfaceView` and using as follows:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView  implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Context context;
    MySurfaceViewThread mThread;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Paint paint;

    int x = 20, y = 20, r = 10;

    public void init() {
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        mThread = new MySurfaceViewThread(getHolder(), this);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }

    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        init();

    }

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public MySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mThread.isRunning = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                mThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//      super.onDraw(canvas);
//      canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
        x += 2;
        y += 2;
        r += 3;
        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(x%255, y%255, (x+y)%255));
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, paint);
        canvas.drawText("x:"+x, 100, 100, paint);
        Log.d("onDraw","onDraw()"+"x:"+x + ",y:"+y+",r:"+r);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("surfaceCreated", "surfaceCreated()");
        mThread.isRunning = true;
        mThread.start();
    }

}
```

I am updating my `Canvas` from a `Thread` which is:

```
public class MySurfaceViewThread extends Thread {

    SurfaceHolder holder;
    MySurfaceView surfaceView;
    boolean isRunning = false;

    public MySurfaceViewThread(SurfaceHolder holder, MySurfaceView surfaceView) {
        Log.d("thread","thread constructor");
        this.holder = holder;
        this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("run","run()");
        while(isRunning) {

            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                synchronized(holder) {
                    surfaceView.onDraw(canvas);
                }
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                Log.d("canvas status", "canvas unlocaked...");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When application starts and its `onDraw()` is called, it draws circle and text as well but on further calls to `onDraw()` it draws nothing. Means nothing changed on screen after first update. Any idea where I am getting wrong? I am new to android and slow learner as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Its very strange. I don't know why this worked. 
I commented the following line from my activity and it runs.

```
surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
```

the activity code is:

```
public class SurfaceViewTutorialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MySurfaceView surfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
//        surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
        surfaceView.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        setContentView(surfaceView);
    }
}
```

If any one knows about this, kindly guide me to the right direction.